# Dockerfile with extension

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Is it possible to have multiple Dockerfile's with different extensions to link some services separately or in other use cases. For example:

```
\Dockerfile.web \Dockerfile.celery
```

and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have multiple Dockerfiles but you can only run one at a time when building an image. By default `docker build` looks for a file named `Dockerfile`. To specify another file use the `-f` flag.

```sh
docker build                     // uses Dockerfile
docker build -f Dockerfile       // does the same as when run without -f
docker build -f Dockerfile.web   // uses Dockerfile.web
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/